# ansible template fail if dictionary is empty

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have the following in an ansible template.

```
           {% if value.http_requests is defined %}
            {% for http_request in value.http_requests %}
http-request    {{ http_request }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

http_requests is usually defined in the playbook like so:

```
   http_requests:
      - randomhttprequest
```

If the variable is defined but the list is empty, then the template will show http-request with no value.

I'm struggling to find a way to fail the playbook even if http_requests list is left empty like this

```
   http_requests:
      -
      -
```

I've tried using length and not none but I cant seem to make it work.

Comment: I don't think that's an empty variable, but rather a list with two empty strings.

Comment: apologies you are right, I'm new to learning these things. the question still remains with an empty list

Comment: do you want to fail the playbook on purpose in the event that the list is empty?

Comment: @RafadeBoas yes

Comment: @user3925030 in your "empty" list example, the list isn't actually empty. it's comprised of two empty lists... in other words: `http_requests = [[], []]`.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**Fail the playbook on purpose in the case that the list was empty.**"*

A: There are many options on how to test it and fail gracefully. For example, you might want to use [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#ansible-builtin-assert-asserts-given-expressions-are-true)

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: value.http_requests|default([])|length == 0
        fail_msg: Error. Tne list value.http_requests is empty.
```

---

In order to check if all the children of a list are "empty" (as in [[], [], ...]) you can use Ansible functions *map, length,* and *sum*. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    http_requests1:
      - randomhttprequest
      - ""
    http_requests2:
      - ""
      - ""
  tasks:
    - name: Sanity http_requests1
      assert:
        that: http_requests1|map('length')|sum > 0
        fail_msg: Error. All items of the list http_requests are empty.
    - name: Sanity http_requests2
      assert:
        that: http_requests2|map('length')|sum > 0
        fail_msg: Error. All items of the list http_requests are empty.
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: http_requests2|map('length')|sum > 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Error. All items of the list http_requests are empty.
```

---

To avoid `undefined variable` error in the template use filter [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default), e.g.

```yaml
{% for http_request in value.http_requests|default([]) %}
http-request    {{ http_request }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Test the length in the loop as well if you want to iterate non-empty string only, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Iterate only non-empty strings
      debug:
        msg: |
          {% for http_request in http_requests1|default([]) %}
          {% if http_request|length > 0 %}
          http-request    {{ http_request }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    http-request    randomhttprequest
```

Comment: i asked the asker if they wanted to fail the playbook on purpose in the case that the list was empty, so this wouldn't answer their problem

Comment: Thank you. This clarified the case. I updated the answer.

Comment: i believe that the asker is looking for how to check if a list of lists is empty (because of their "empty list" example). using the length here wouldn't be enough (see my answer below)

Comment: Sure. I did already. And updated the answer on this case as well. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice and very elegant!

Answer (score -1):

In order to check if all the children of a list are "empty" (as in `[[], [], ...]`) you can use some Python built-ins:

```py
# This will return True
example_list = [[], []]
empty = all(not l for l in map(lambda l: bool(l), example_list))

# This will return False
example_list = [[1, 2], []]
empty = all(not l for l in map(lambda l: bool(l), example_list))
```

I built a sample playbook that does exactly this:

```yaml
- name: Check for empty list example
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    example_list:
        -
        -
  tasks:
    # Calling Python here is necessary because Jinja2 doesn't have 
    # an `all()` filter, so I had to improvise. 
    - name: check for empty list
      register: result
      args: 
        stdin: |
          print(all(not l for l in map(lambda l: bool(l), {{ example_list }})))
      command: python

    - debug:
        msg: 'list is empty'
      # String comparison because we're `print()`ing the result
      # of the Python expression...
      when: result.stdout == "True"

    - name: lets fail
      debug:
        msg: 'list is not empty'
      failed_when: result.stdout == "True"
```

This is, without a doubt, very ugly. However, it gets the job done.